# Merging a DataFrame with a GeoDataFrame based on two keys

Tags: python, geopandas, merge, pandas

I have a `GeoDataFrame` called `gdf_points` with a list of `POINT`s:

| index | NAME | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | POINT(A) |
| 2 | B | POINT(B) |

And another DataFrame called `df_names` in which each `POINT` is associated with possibly more than one row:

| index | Point name | Properties |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | bla |
| 2 | A | bli |
| 3 | B | blu |
| 4 | B | ble |

And I would like to merge those to to another `GeoDataFrame` with the following strcture:

| index | Point name | Properties | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | bla | POINT(A) |
| 2 | A | bli | POINT(A) |
| 3 | B | blu | POINT(B) |
| 4 | B | ble | POINT(B) |

I tried the following line:

```
merged_df = df_names.merge(gdf_points, on='NAME', how='left')
```

But received a `KeyError: 'NAME'`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no column named `NAME` in your right df, that is why you get `KeyError`. Use `left_on` and `right_on` to specify both column names:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"NAME":["A","B"], "x":[1,2], "y":[2,1]})
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(x=df.x, y=df.y))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={"Point name":["A","A","B","B"], "prop":[1,2,3,4]})

merged = df.merge(right=df2, how="left", left_on="NAME", right_on="Point name")
```